# Better way of creating jQuery accordion menus?

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I've been trying to learn Javascript/jQuery and attempted to build an accordion menu by essentially copy-pasting the code on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp) page. However, when I try and make multiple divs, only the first one will work. If I switch the IDs to Classes, then both divs expand when I click. This is the script I've grabbed from W3Schools;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Then in the HTML I have

```
        <div class="flip">Category A</div>
        <div class="panel">
            One <br/>
            Two <br/>
            Three <br/>
            Four <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="flip">Category B</div>
        <div class="panel">
            One <br/>
            Two <br/>
            Three <br/>
            Four <br/>
        </div>
```

And the CSS -

```
#flip, #panel{
    width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#flip{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #cc44ff;
}

#panel{
    display: none;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

I've managed to get it to work if I duplicate the functions and classes and give them new names, but it seems messy and unnecessary. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I've posted it to JSFiddle as well - http://jsfiddle.net/Nikf/k1wstb5n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$(".panel")` addresses *all* matching elements, not just the one of interest.

Starting from the clicked element `this`, you can "traverse the DOM" to select the *next* `.panel`, ignoring all others :

```
$(".flip").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k1wstb5n/2/) (using the HTML from the question with appropriately adjusted CSS)

Comment: That's not a good idea because that's too much dependant on the html.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Worked a treat for me. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

[**Update Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/farskid/k1wstb5n/1/)
Change id to class:

```
<body>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="cat">
                <div class="flip">Category A</div>
                <div class="panel">
                    One <br/>
                    Two <br/>
                    Three <br/>
                    Four <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cat">
                <div class="flip">Category B</div>
                <div class="panel">
                    One <br/>
                    Two <br/>
                    Three <br/>
                    Four <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: ;
}   

.flip, .panel{
    width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.flip{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #cc44ff;
}

.panel{
    display: none;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

And by using a `.cat` container for the items just use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, I gave your code a shot and it works well once I add the "cat" class. Could you explain or give more information as to why adding that class makes it work, and why it's better practice?

Comment: The jQuery code you were using was not working as expected because you were targeting all '.panel' elements. using a container such as '.cat' would restrict the code to the local container of each item and therefore you code control the .panel like I showed. The answer that you accepted above is right but is not general and too dependant on the html.